# existence of quotient set in universe

Tags: elementary-set-theory

When set *U* satisfy these:

1. $\mathbb{N} \in U$
2. $\forall x \forall y ( x \in y \wedge y \in U \Rightarrow x \in U )$
3. $\forall I \in U$, for all map $f : I \rightarrow U$, $\bigcup_{i \in I} f(i) \in U$
4. $\forall x \in U ( P(x) \in U ) \ \ \ \ ( P(x) = \{ y \ | \ y \subseteqq x \} )$

Is this proposition true?

For all equivalence relation $\sim$ on U, $U/{\sim} = \{ C \in P(U) \ | \ \exists x \in C \forall y \in U (y \in C \iff x \sim y) \} \in U$

I cannot give this a proof.

Comment: $\forall x\forall y(x\in y\land y\in U)$ is a strange condition -- it says that everything is an element of everything _and_ everything is an element of $U$, which cannot possibly be true in ordinary set theory. You almost certainly mean something different from this -- possibly $\forall x\forall y(x\in y\land y\in U\to x\in U)$?

Comment: Also, what exactly is it you want to prove? Your last formula seems just to be a _definition_ of what $C/{\sim}$ means -- what is it you will prove _about_ it?

Comment: It was my mistake, I corrected it.

Comment: You probably wanted the second condition to be $\ldots\rightarrow x\in U$, rather than $x\in y$.

Comment: Also, if you take $\sim$ to be the tautological relation, namely every two elements are equivalent, then $U/{\sim}=\{U\}$, which in turn would imply that $U\in U$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your three conditions amount to saying that $U$ is a transitive model of ZF with some additional bells and whistles, namely that the model satisfies a *second-order* Replacement axiom where every function definable at the metalevel can be used. (This implies that the model's power sets are true power sets, and therefore that the model satisfies the Axiom of Choice if the ambient universe does).

It is consistent with ZFC that no such $U$ exists, in which case your answer is, vacuously, **yes**.

On the other hand it is conceivable that an $U$ actually exists. (If $\kappa$ is an inaccessible cardinal, then $V_\kappa$ seems to qualify). And in that case the answer is strongly **no**: For *every* equivalence relation $\sim$ on $U$, we have $U/{\sim} \notin U$.

Namely, your condition (2) with $f$ being the identity on $I$ tells us that the union of any set in $U$ is itself in $U$. Therefore, $U/{\sim}\in U$ would imply $U\in U$. Even if the ambient universe is ill-founded, Russell's paradox now obtains a contradiction in the usual way.

Comment: It's not that $V_\kappa$ "seems to qualify", it's the only candidate. We can prove that every transitive model of $\sf ZF_2$ is $V_\kappa$ for an inaccessible $\kappa$.